# Iron Man comic where he goes back in time and is defeated

Tags: comics, iron-man, episode-identification, marvel

I read this comic a long time ago. In it, Iron Man traveled back to the past (a time where people used swords and armor). He gets imprisoned and beaten up. His girlfriend in the present is an archaeologist, or something like that. She digs and find the Iron Man suit's head with a skull on it. I haven't read the rest, yet.

Answer (score 5):

I'm fairly sure you're describing "[In Shining Iron](http://www.comicvine.com/iron-man-59-in-shining-iron-part-1/4000-131901/)", a 2002 three-part story in which:

> Tony Stark invents a time-machine and travels back to the land of
>   knights and chivalry.

[image]

Comment: Do you have amazing Google powers or do you just know all this stuff? Your knowledge is extreme! :)

Comment: @MacCooper - I used my google-fu for this one. A quick search for "**"Iron Man" AND archaeologist and "time travel"**" led me to http://www.comicbookreligion.com/?c=35548&archaeologists. From there it was a choice of two, and only one is female.

Comment: @MacCooper - Richard lives for this stuff.

Comment: I am so sad that I am working so much now. I used to be the go-to guy for comic stuff. <Le sigh.>

Comment: @Thaddeus - vive le nouveau roi! ;-)

Comment: Thanks man! I tried lot of searches about ironman time travel but only got doomsday results. Thanks